# oledb connection exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oledb

This is my code

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Machine Name;Initial Catalog=MyTestDatabase;";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
DataTable result = new DataTable();
try
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("get_holidays", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(result);
}
```

> $exception {"Invalid authorization specification"} is thrown during
>   conn.open().

Comment: How do you connect to the sql server? by means of windows authentication or sql server authentication?

Comment: I have used same format for another machine in the same network. Here i am trying to connect to the server in the same system  which i am working

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 - to help you out with any connection string. Also put your conn into a using so it is disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection string format:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
```

or

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Integrated Security=SSPI` to your connection string especially when username and password are not specified. In this case current [Windows account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) credentials are used for authentication.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ServerName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=databaseName
```

Answer (score 0):

no `username` and `password` in `connection string`

Comment: It must be in the correct format still and if not specifying username password then you can specify Integrated Security

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Machine Name;Initial Catalog=MyTestDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

If will not work locally - then you have no access to your Sql Server

Comment: You using login-password or Windows Auth?