# problems with sql local db

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to understand how I can use sql local db for my projects.

I created local DB with Studio's creator, put tables, some columns and rows in it. Then I'm trying to connect to this DB and show data in Grid.

As I understand in this case, I have to use OleDB:

```
        OleDbConnection ole = new OleDbConnection();
        ole.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" + "data source=Database1.sdf;";
        ole.Open();
```

An error occurs on the line `ole.Open()`

> Invalid autorization specification

What is my mistake?

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665673/oledb-connection-exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665673/oledb-connection-exception)

Comment: For those who have marked this question as a duplicate, if you read correctly the code and the comments to the answer below, you will see that the real problem is that user was trying to connect to a `SqlCompact` file with `OleDb` because he was thinking it works like *Microsoft Access*. So the answer is not on the duplicate link because it refers to connect to `SqlServer` via `OleDb` and this is totally inappropriate here. The correct answer is 'use `SqlServerCe` class if possible'.

Comment: @Tapas Mahata, in your link, someone tries to connect to sql server. and I tried to connect to *.sdf file. I had another task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sdf` extension in your connection string means it is not a Sql Server local DB, but a Sqlcompact file.

- You should add the reference to Sql server compact (you need to have
  included the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace that is in the
  `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`) and then use `SqlceConnection` instead
  of `OleDbconnection` (and remove the provider part on your connection
  string)
- If the using of `OleDbconnection` is required, set the correct
  provider in your connection string
  http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce#microsoft-sqlserver-ce-oledb-3-5

Comment: aaaa, I thought that .sdf is the same as .mdb (Microsoft Access)... And that is why I tried to use the same methods...